# Tab Bar Controller items collapsing

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I don't know why/how this is happening.
On Simulator it works fine but while running it on device the items are collapsing with each other.

[image]

Comment: do you maybe use storyboard references?

Comment: Please check the image in the bundle .

Comment: Are you using TabBarController ??

Comment: Images in the bundle are proper. And Yes i'm using TabBarController

Comment: In which simulator you have checked and in which device you are running now ?

Comment: From where you are assigning images?? You should assign images from ViewControllers associated with tabbar in TabBarController.

Comment: I have tried running the app on 4s,5s,6,6+ (Simulator) And On 4s Device that items are collapsing.

Comment: Yeah I have assigned images from ViewControllers. It's not just Images that is collapsing. The whole item is collapsing as "Edit Profile"(TabBar Name) is also visible in it.